# Reading from filehandle failed: latexmk

Tags: mac, latexmk

I have been using MacTex/TeXShop/xelatexmk for many years on my personal Mac, and am trying to set my new office Mac up with it.

I have copied the inactive engines to the active engine directory and, so far as I can tell, set up all relevant parameters in TeXShop to what I had before.

The run starts with:

```
Rc files read:
  /Users/kfeuerherm/Library/TeXShop/bin/latexmkrcedit
  /Users/kfeuerherm/Library/TeXShop/bin/tslatexmk/xelatexmkrc
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 4 Apr. 2023. Version 4.80.
```

then continues on as expected, but eventually halts with

```
Latexmk: Log file says output to '2305-CJAS.pdf'
Reading from filehandle failed at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk line 10711.
Latexmk: Bibliography file(s) form .bcf file:
```

followed by a list of `.bib` files.

For lack of a better idea, I've checked permissions on the `latexmk` file, seem the same as before, and am now at a loss as to how to move forward in correcting this.

UPDATE: the issue seems somehow to be connected to the fact that the files live on OneDrive... though I do have synchronization paused. Once I move the whole file tree to my desktop, the problem disappears.

However, I would prefer not to have to do that....

UPDATE 230731: in the process of debugging, the problem seems to have been suspended *for the time being*. If the situation changes, I will provide an additional update.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with permissions on latexmk or anything like that.  The error message is from what latexmk does on line 10711.  That line is calling a function external to latexmk that reads input from an already opened file, which is one of the source files of the document.  The error is from a failure of a reading from that file, presumably on OneDrive.  Did you try turning sync on?  (I don't use OneDrive, so that's a shot in the dark.)

Comment: Could you contact me at the e-mail address in the latexmk documentation.  This is probably going to need more debugging than is convenient here.

Comment: Ok, I will look for that. In the meantime: synch is turned off because otherwise, OneDrive renames things faster than *TeX can deal with them and we go into an infinite loop, usually. Two new insights: Moving the whole thing to a NAS works, but is slow (no surprise; I need to put the stuff, ideally, where it's accessible from multiple machines). Secondly, on the OneDrive, the aux files seem to end up one level up from the main `.tex` file.